# why my react native component keep refreshing?

Tags: javascript, react-native

hi i am trying to build react native app i am using expo
i build a screen to show data and calculate a number using hooks
but i face that my component keep rendering so i cant press in the buttons easily , which lead me to can't calculate the number ,
this is my code how i can stop this continuous refreshing

if i but console statements inside the component it keep printing in console and not stop

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-paper";
import axios from "axios";
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function Confirm() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState("0");
  const [total, setTotal] = useState("0");
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState({});
  try {
    //Retrieving user token, reserved nanny information and user location value from AsyncStorage
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["token", "nany", "location"]).then((res) => {
      var nany = JSON.parse(res[1][1]);
      var location = JSON.parse(res[2][1]);
      setInfo(nany);
      console.log("hi3");
      setSelectedLocation(location);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }


  const onSubmit = () => {
    axios
      .post("http://192.168.127.43:5000/send2", [selectedLocation, total, info])
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  function calculateTotal() {
    console.log(info.cost * value);
    var totalCost = info.cost * value;
    setTotal(totalCost);
    alert("Your reservation done \n Your service costs: " + total);
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <>
        <View>
          <Card
            title={info.name}
            caption={info.cost + "  JD  /H"}
           
          >
            <View
           
            >
              <Text>{info.place}</Text>
            </View>
          </Card>
          <View>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.text}>
                Enter how many hours you need our service
              </Text>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
                value={value}
              ></TextInput>
            </View>

            <View>
              <Button
                mode="contained"
                onPress={calculateTotal}
              >
                <Text>Calculate total</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <View>
              <Button
                mode="contained"
                onPress={onSubmit}
              >
                <Text>Done</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Button
                title="Submit"
                mode="contained"
              >
                <Text>Cancel</Text>
              </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </>
    </View>
  );
}
// export default Confirm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Nothing looks wrong in your code but for safer side wrap try and catch inside useEffect.

useEffect(()=>{
  try {
    //Retrieving user token, reserved nanny information and user location value from AsyncStorage
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["token", "nany", "location"]).then((res) => {
      var nany = JSON.parse(res[1][1]);
      var location = JSON.parse(res[2][1]);
      setInfo(nany);
      console.log("hi3");
      setSelectedLocation(location);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
,[]);
```